# asp.net getting the selected HtmlInputRadioButton or HtmlInputCheckbox

Tags: asp.net

using asp.net 4.0

I'm generating HtmlInputRadioButton like the following into a table control.

```
<table runat="server" id="table_impact" cellspacing="1" 
        cellpadding="4" enableviewstate="true">  </table>
```

Code is

```
HtmlInputRadioButton rbd = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                        rbd.Value = "";
                        rbd.Checked = true; 
td.Controls.Add(rbd); 
tr.Cells.Add(td);
```

But when I try to read that value back the checked property is always the value I sent when adding the controls to the table.
it's as if HtmlInputRadioButton.Checked is simply looking for the checked attribute and does not reflect that the user selected a different radio button.

for the HtmlInputRadioButton I've insured that they all have the same name so it works properly in the browser.

How do I find the users selected radio button?

Comment: Have you used runat="server" attribute in them?

Comment: @Praveen: the HtmlInputRadioButton is added programattically and gets the naming container prefix and I can find it on a post back so... yes

Comment: Can you post some more code? (code-behind etc.)

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl: just added a sample of how the HmtlInputRadio button is being created. the real thing is a lot more conplex but i think you get the idea.

Comment: I don´t understand.. you cannot uncheck such a button, can you? Am I missing something? Hope you can solve the problem by yourself...

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl: so long as you have 1+ radio buttons with the same name attribute you can toggle between them.  And yes I did solve it myself: buried in the code was a bug (bad logic) that caused the table to be re-generated thus it was always in it's default state: i.e. it was reading the checked value.

Answer (score 2):

if it is generated programmatically then you need to generate it again before load viewstat event when request comes to server next time, so that ASP.net can populate relevant data on controls.

You need to execute same code which generates  HtmlInputRadioButton.